# How to reduce the size of datepicker in textbox?

Tags: jquery-ui

I have been able to use datepicker in textbox but I can't figure out reducing its default size??
Any help is appreciated.Thanks iin advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the font size so it gets smaller, like this:

```
.ui-datepicker {
  font-size: .8em; /* put small value here*/
}
```

See [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/yCSM3/)

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly:

```
input.ui-datepicker{
 font-size:10px;
}
```